# Does tcp.analysis.flags in Wireshark find bad TCP packet?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

Let me start by prefixing my knowledge of Wireshark is very limited.

Context : I'm investigating logs between a server hosted files and an AV that supported ICAP protocol. In this logs I'm very interesting about the string :

`Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time`

I though a trace could be a good idea to investigate this logs so I'm using `icap` flag to find all record about icap transaction.

As icap is based on the TCP/IP pile my question is :

> Should I use `icap and tcp.analysis.flags` as a flag in Wireshark to find bad TCP packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a bad TCP packet, unless you are expecting to find a packet corrupted on its way to your capture point, in which case the NIC might drop it before sending it up to the OS.

The string you've shared it just means one party tried to connect to the remote party and never received a response, so this is what you want to look for in Wireshark:

(Assume 1.2.3.4 is the client and 4.3.2.1 is the server)

- A SYN packet (tcp.flags.syn == 1) from client to server (ip.src == 1.2.3.4 & ip.dst == 4.3.2.1) that it has been retransmitted (tcp.analysis.retransmission)
- When you have located it, right-click on that packet and select "Follow TCP stream". Close the pop up window you'll get with the raw contents of the connection.

You'll be left with a filter on a specific tcp stream and you might see this behaviour:

- A SYN packet is sent
- A second SYN packet is sent 3 seconds later
- A third SYN packet is sent 6 seconds later
- A fourth SYN packet is sent 12 seconds later

And you might never see a packet coming from 4.3.2.1 to 1.2.3.4;

Your real problem might be:

- A firewall in the path.
- Service is not listening at destination.
- There's no route to the destination, so the packet gets sent to a default route at some point and dropped silently (probably leaving your Internet edge?)